# Firestore Query in Angularfire not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I've got a problem with the angularfire firestore query. Apparently the only working opStr in the where Query seems to be "==". I am trying to get documents with a value >= 1 but I am unable to get it to work.
So what I have tested is what I get when I query with different WhereFilterOps. 
In my Firestore DB I've got a document with the key/value pair mytestvalue/1:number.
So I've created a query with the where clause:

```
.where("mytestvalue", ">=", 1)
```

And I do not get back the object. If I change the clause to:

```
.where("mytestvalue", "==", 1)
```

I do get the result I am expecting. Am I missing something? Do I need to add an index or something to be able to use the ">=" Operator?
I'm currently using @angular/fire 5.3.0. Do I need to upgrade to 6.0?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god, sorry. I DID need an index. Guess I had the answer but was not able to use my brain properly.